# I guess they changed the logo

Tags: discussion

Well, that's a different and not particularly good (or in no way graphically says "home improvement" to me, anyway) logo for Home Improvement today.

[image: New logo, whatever it means...]

Some graphic designer is laughing all the way to the bank.

Some vice president in charge of marketing design needs to be let go...

So, what in {bleep} is this supposed to communicate, other than the above two points, the second of which hardly ever gets implemented, even when it obviously should be?

Comment: I keep a menorah on sites and light a candle after every inspection step that gets passed.   Obviously this has caught on and SE has commemorated the idea.     SE could have been a huge global company...  but a company with a really good idea executed in the worst possible way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all sites, not just DIY.SE. You can follow the meta issue over here: [Favicon sprites are offset in site list dropdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381137/favicon-sprites-are-offset-in-site-list-dropdown)

For background, they use a [single large image](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=bafa22065134) of all the site logos and other small graphics, and then pick out the correct picture with some CSS and math. The bad offset looks like they got the math wrong.

Comment: Vice presidents are notoriously bad at math, so let a few go anyway...